# WCSF Random assembly manifest definition does not match assembly ref in .NET 2.0

Tags: enterprise-library, wcsf

I'm running WCSF Feb 2008 along with Enterprise Library 3.1 and noticed that randomly I get the "fun"

*Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public ... The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

Usually this wouldn't be worth mentioning on stackoverflow, but the strange thing is that the first time I fire this up it breaks, but if I close it down and simply hit F11 again - it works .... strange.  Does anyone know why this might break sometimes, but not others?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to my version of the data access DLL I was adding.  I found that if I went to the following:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Client
>   Software Factory February
>   2008\Microsoft Practices Library

and imported this specific data access DLL instead of the one I compiled myself from the Enterprise Library 3.1 installer, everything worked great.